# Can we have common kanban board for multiple projects in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

There are around 6 projects which we are handling , For all six projects we have different azure boards so we would like to have single board for all projects . Is it possible ? If so how ?

I'm looking for the way to get all the tickets into one board

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [**Delivery Plans**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops).

Delivery Plans supports these tasks:

- View up to 20 team backlogs, including a mix of backlogs and teams from different projects.
- Add custom portfolio backlogs and epics.
- View work items that span several iterations.
- Reset start date and target date through drag-and-drop borders.
- Add backlog items to a team from a plan.
- View rollup progress of features, epics, and other portfolio items.
- View dependencies that exist between work items.
- Enable stakeholders to view plans.

It should be the nearest way to satisfy your demands.